# How to use scala.collection.immutable.Map's API sum directly?

Tags: scala

I want to sum the `Map("one" -> 2, "two" -> 3, "three" -> 4)`'s values `2+3+4`, of course I can use the following methods:

1. `Map("one" -> 2, "two" -> 3, "three" -> 4).foldLeft(0)(_ + _._2)`
2. `Map("one" -> 2, "two" -> 3, "three" -> 4).values.sum()`

I found `Map` has a another more direct API sum: [def sum: A](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/#scala.collection.concurrent.Map), but, I don't search any example about this `API`, How to use it?

Comment: That isn't actually the full type signature of `sum`; you may want to read [*Why are scaladoc method signatures wrong?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132459/why-are-scaladoc-method-signatures-wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `sum[B >: (A, B)](implicit num: Numeric[B]): B`, as you see, it needs the `implicit` parameter and the parameter type is `Numeric[B]` type.

> Scala `Numeric` is `trait` that defined a series of math operation.
>   http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html

for your case, the type is  `Map[String, Int]`, so you need to implement the `implicit` for `Numeric[(String, Int)]` for  `sum` method, like:

```
 trait MyTupleNumeric extends Numeric[(String, Int)] {
    def plus(x: (String, Int), y: (String, Int)) = ("", x._2 + y._2)

    override def minus(x: (String, Int), y: (String, Int)): (String, Int) = ("", x._2 - x._2)

    override def times(x: (String, Int), y: (String, Int)): (String, Int) = ("", x._2 * y._2)

    override def negate(x: (String, Int)): (String, Int) = ("", -x._2)

    override def fromInt(x: Int): (String, Int) = ("", x)

    override def toInt(x: (String, Int)): Int = x._2

    override def toLong(x: (String, Int)): Long = x._2.toLong

    override def toFloat(x: (String, Int)): Float = x._2.toFloat

    override def toDouble(x: (String, Int)): Double = x._2.toDouble

    override def compare(x: (String, Int), y: (String, Int)): Int = x._2 - y._2
  }

  implicit object MyTupleNumericImplicit extends MyTupleNumeric

  val f = implicitly[Numeric[(String, Int)]] // implicitly is used find implicits base on the type
  println(f.plus(("one", 2), ("two", 3)))
  val r = Map("one" -> 2, "two" -> 3, "three" -> 4)
  println(r.sum._2)
  println(r.sum(MyTupleNumericImplicit))
```

As the above code, we have implement own `Numeric` type with `(String, Int)`, and implements methods.

And we `implicit` this into our scope, so we can use `implicitly` to get the `function` and call.

And the `sum` method also could find the `implicit` parameter for `Numeric[(String, Int)]`

Answer (score 2):

The Map.sum method doesn't do what you want -- your functions look good as they are.

The reason why Map has a sum method is that *all* `TraversableOnce` classes have a sum method, which only works if the collection type is numeric.  However, a `Map[K, V]` is a `TraversableOnce[(K, V)]`, so this approach won't work (the key-value tuple is not a numeric type).