# scala - What Map[(A, B)] mean?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm reading the Scala Map doc, and got confused by this method signature

```
def zipAll[B](that: collection.Iterable[B], thisElem: A, thatElem: B): Map[(A, B)]
```

What does `Map[(A, B)]` mean?  Is it the same as `Map[A, B]`?  Thanks

Link to the doc:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html

Comment: Means nothing, it's wrong and I have no idea why that thing is still there.

Comment: By "still" do you mean that this is a known / already reported issue?

Comment: Actually, I think my question duplicates this https://stackoverflow.com/q/26132459/842860

Comment: I think this question has come up in the past (I'm talking about years ago) and I remember seeing a ticket somewhere that states that the scaladoc are simply wrong in most of its parts, you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132459/why-are-scaladoc-method-signatures-wrong).

Comment: You are right about the dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm reading the Scala Map doc, and got confused by this method signature
>
> ```
> def zipAll[B](that: collection.Iterable[B], thisElem: A, thatElem: B): Map[(A, B)]
> ```

This is *not* the method signature. This is the "[use case signature](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scaladoc/for-library-authors.html#usage-tags)". It is a *simplified* signature that indicates the most common usage of the method. The *real* signature is:

```
def zipAll[B, A1 >: (K, V), That](that: GenIterable[B], thisElem: A1, thatElem: B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Map[K, V], (A1, B), That]): That
```

> What does `Map[(A, B)]` mean?

`(A, B)` is syntactic sugar for `Tuple2[A, B]`, i.e. a pair (aka 2-tuple) type.

> Is it the same as `Map[A, B]`?

No, `Map[Tuple2[A, B]]` is not the same as `Map[A, B]`: the former applies the `Map` type constructor to a *single* argument `(A, B)` whereas the latter applies the `Map` type constructor to *two* arguments, `A` and `B`.

Note that the `Map` type constructor has two parameters, so the former is simply an error: you cannot apply the `Map` type constructor to only a single argument, you need two.

Remember that the signature you saw is only a use case, it is written by a *human* for *humans* to read, it is **not verified by the type checker**. As such, it can contain bugs.

Note also that there are a lot of repetitive type signatures and use cases across the entire collection hierarchy, those are generated by additional scripts. It looks like one of those scripts simply generates a wrong signature for `Map.zipAll` (note that the same bug exists in the other `zip` variants on `Map`, too).

A little experiment shows that `zip` takes the key-value pairs of the map as the first element of the result pairs and the elements from the `that` collection as the second element of the result pairs, and constructs a map from that, which results in a map which has the original key-value pairs as keys and the `other` elements as values:

```
Map("one" → 1, "two" → 2) zip Seq('a, 'b, 'c)
//=> Map((one, 1) -> 'a, (two, 2) -> 'b)
```

So, the simplified use case signature should be something like this:

```
def zipAll[A](that: collection.Iterable[A], thisElem: (K, V), thatElem: A): Map[(K, V), A]
```

It looks like the scripts get confused and substitute `(K, V)` for `A` in the signature.

Comment: So what do you get ? Should it just be `Map[A,B]` ?

Comment: See the update. In some sense, yes, you get `Map[A, B]`, but the `A`s are the original key-value pairs of the `this` map, i.e. `type A = (K, V)`, so you get `Map[(K, V), B]` as a result.